# Use HTML template to create pages from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been asked to design an "intelligent home" website based on an API provided. I have "Rooms" (actual rooms in a house) and "Devices" in each room.

I have a page (HTML file) "Rooms" which contains a list of all the availabe rooms in the API. I have another HTML file named "RoomX" which is the "template" for all the rooms. It has a list of all the devices in the specified room.

I don't know how to "create" and link new "Room" pages every time I add a Room to the Rooms list. Example: I added "Room 1" as a room in the API and as an element in the page "Rooms". I click on it, and right now, it takes me to my "RoomX" page. I want to create "copies" of that "RoomX" page; so that when I click on the new room I created, I can access a page that has the selected room title and its devices.

The creation and deletion of rooms is dinamic, so I would need to create these pages depending on the user's needs. I am only just starting to use HTML, CSS and JS (I am using JQuery on my page), so I would appreciate an extensive explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have an API ready and they asked you to design the front end? or are you supposed to design everything?

if the API is already made please go back to it and look for the specification, Usually the response is going to be a JSON.

example:

let's say that to get all available rooms > yourwebsite.com/rooms
to get one room, for example room 1 > yourwebsite.com/rooms/1

if that was made for you already, all you need to make is the UI + use jquery AJAX to get the json response and display it

if nothing was made then pretty much doing it dynamically with html is impossible. What you need to do then is:

1. pick any RESTful API framework and learn it if you don't know one already
2. make a restful api that generates json responses
3. make the UI using either front-end frameworks or by classic html, css and js